# cocoa: which method I should use to initialize properties instead of awakeFromNib

Tags: macos, cocoa

[image]

TableData is a subclass of NSObject as datasource and table delegate for a view-based table. The `awakeFromNib` method of TableData will run many times because I'm using view-based table. If TableData is a subclass of NSViewController, I can use `loadView:` to finish my task, but TableData is a subclass of NSObject, my question is:

1. which method I should use instead of `awakeFromNib` to initialize TableData properties?

Comment: **awakeFromNib will run many times** Are you sure about that?

Comment: yes,  because every view-based table cell will call it.

Comment: from your nib file I guess it is in a windowController, if so try `- (void)windowDidLoad` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how you create your window, but you can do in this way:

AppDelegate.m

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application

    fMainWinDelegate = nil;
    fMainWinDelegate = [[MainWinDelegate alloc] init];
    [fMainWinDelegate showWindow];
}
```

MainWindowDelegate.m

```
- (id)initWithWindow:(NSWindow *)AWindow
{
    NSLog(@"MainWinDelegate::initWithWindow");
    self = [super initWithWindow:AWindow];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code here.
        NSLog(@"MainWinDelegate::initWithWindow, we have self!");
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib 
{
    NSLog(@"MainWinDelegate::awakeFromNib");
    // only for debug and to be sure that is called many times
}

- (void)showWindow {
    NSLog(@"MainWinDelegate::showWindow");

    if (!self.window) {
        [NSBundle loadNibNamed:@"MainWin" owner:self];

        NSLog(@"MainWinDelegate::showWindow init part");
        // do your init here
    }

    [self.window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];

    NSLog(@"MainWinDelegate::showWindow end");
}
```

This is the log:

```
MainWinDelegate::initWithWindow
MainWinDelegate::initWithWindow, we have self!
MainWinDelegate::showWindow
MainWinDelegate::awakeFromNib
MainWinDelegate::showWindow init part
MainWinDelegate::showWindow end
```

Answer (score 0):

You might choose either:

```
@interface MONTableData : NSObject

// a designated initializer:
- (id)init;
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)pCoder;

// or when the `TableData`'s input data source is set:
- (void)setPhotoAlbum:(MONPhotoAlbum *)pPhotoAlbum;

@end
```